# How to derive low pass filter $\frac{N}{N+S}$

Tags: lowpass-filter, laplace-transform

I watched [the video for PID control system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dUVdrs1e18) where it mentioned the Laplace domain function and low pass filter to be $\frac{N}{N+S}$.
I used asymptotic analysis to see that it made sense. However, I'm interested in how it was originally derived. How did Laplace domain function lead to the low pass filter?

Comment: I am not sure that it is a minimal question. Can you edit the question in a way that does not require to see the movie in the link?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to see that the transfer-function magnitude is inverse proportional to the frequency. In this case, you replace $S$ with $i\omega$ and you get that the transfer function magnitude decays with the frequency$|G(\omega)|=\left|\frac{n}{ n+i\omega}\right|$